# Extract the selected zone on a picture with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OPENCV to detect a face in a picture and I want ot extract it, so i have the photo with a man and the expected result is a jpg image with only the seleted face

[image]

I have detect the face but if someone can help me to extract this face and save it!

Thank you all

Comment: Try searching for image cropping and pass the values you place in `cv2.rectangle()`

Comment: > one tiny change, you need to do img[y:y+h, x:x+w] (the old "opencv counts in x,y while numpy deals in y,x" trick) OK that is working well! Thank you guys for your answers! Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a single line to your program.

Consider a variable `detected_face`, and do the following:

```
detected_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('face.jpg', detected_face)
```

You will have a `.jpg`file of ONLY the face stored in your directory

Comment: one tiny change, you need to do img[y:y+h, x:x+w] (the old "opencv counts in x,y while numpy deals in y,x" trick)